# Purge parachain issue

Tags: blockchain, substrate, polkadot

I want to purge my parachain collator node, but I got this error

```
Input("Error parsing spec file: missing field `relay_chain` at line 143 column 1")（cannot purge parachain）
```

This is the command I used to purge my parachain

```
./target/release/parachain-collator  purge-chain --base-path /tmp/parachain/alice --chain rococo-custom.json
```

This is the command I used to run this parachain-collator

```
./target/release/parachain-collator \
--alice \
--collator \
--force-authoring \
--parachain-id 2000 \
--base-path /tmp/parachain/alice \
--port 40333 \
--ws-port 8844 \
-- \
--execution wasm \
--chain rococo-custom.json \
--port 30343 \
--ws-port 9977
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
./XXX/parachain-collator purge-chain --base-path <your collator DB path set above>
```

no need args for chainspec.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I tried but I still got an error: 
`Error: Input("Relay chain argument error: Invalid input: rococo-local only supported with rococo-native feature enabled.")`
The command I used is:
`./target/release/parachain-collator purge-chain --base-path /tmp/parachain/alice`
I’m pretty sure I used `/tmp/parachain/alice` as my DB path set when I boot this collator node.

Comment: @luckysky why not try boot at a new dir? abandon or remove the old one.